# How to import worksheet with desired columns? Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, import, worksheet

I'm able to import worksheets successfully to my workbook. But is it possible to just import the columns that I want? The data is really huge and I don't want to have the trouble to go through every part of the cells.
Below are my codes:

```
Sub ImportSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim activeWB As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim oWS      As String
    Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    FilePath = "C:\Report.xlsx"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    wb.Sheets("Report").Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
    activeWB.Activate
    wb.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm breaking protocol here but this is a completely different approach and the option to *Add Another Answer* was there. This method uses the *'copy to new worksheet'* approach which should be easier on limited resources.

```
Sub ImportSheet()
    Dim iWB As Workbook, aWB As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim FilePath As String, v As Long, vCOLs As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    FilePath = "C:\Report.xlsx"
    vCOLs = Array(1, 13, 6, 18, 4, 2) 'columns to copy in this order

    Set aWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    With aWB
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Set ws = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        '.name = "Report"   'you can name the new ws but do NOT duplicate
    End With
    Set iWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    With iWB.Sheets("Report").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Cells = .Cells.Value
        For v = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
            .Columns(vCOLs(v)).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(1, v + 1)
        Next v
    End With
    iWB.Close False

    Set iWB = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set aWB = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My primary concern here is not knowing the layout of the *'Report'* worksheet. The boundaries of the  `.CurrentRegion` are dictated by the first fully blank column to the right and the first fully blank row down. A block of data rarely has this but worksheets called *Report* often do.

Comment: Is it necessary to add .Cells = .Cells.Value ? I tried the code and get "Out of Memory" error.

Comment: @De De De De - If the cells you are copying away from the original contain formulas that reference cells you are leaving behind, there will be other issues. Perhaps it is sufficient to convert only the cells that are being copied. Move that line into the `For ... Next` loop above the copy line and change it to `.Columns(vCOLs(v)).Cells = .Columns(vCOLs(v)).Cells.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the freshly opened workbook (without saving or warnings) after the copy so I would suggest that you loop through the columns you do not want and delete then prior to the copy. Incorporate this snippet into your existing code

```
Dim v As Long, vNoCopy As Variant, wb As Workbook
vNoCopy = Array(1, 3, 5, 7)   'should in ascending order (reversed below)
With wb.Sheets("Report")
    .Cells = .Cells.Value   'just in case there are referenced formulas involved
    For v = UBound(vNoCopy) To LBound(vNoCopy) Step -1
        .Columns(vNoCopy(v)).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next v
    wb.Sheets("Report").Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
End With
wb.Close False
```

That should remove columns A, C, E & G from the report before copying. Closing without saving should leave the original Report.xlsx unaffected.

Comment: This is a good answer. Besides deleting the columns that I do not need, can I go for the opposite? Which is to just select the columns that I need. There are 80+ columns though and I need around six of them.

Comment: @Tim Williams - +1 Good catch & an excellent point. I definitely missed the ball on that. Corrected above.

Comment: @De De De De - You could a) only copy the six you need as long as you recorded the row of insertion to a variable for reuse in subsequent columns; b) only list the columns you wanted to keep instead of listing all of the ones you wanted to delete; c) delete the ones you want to keep from the following (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80)

Comment: If you're deleting stuff from the source worksheet, it would be a good idea to open it read-only (append `ReadOnly:=True` to the line `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)` in the original code)